# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oauth-2.0

Everyone

I have faced a issues when implement Google Login in React.js
I used @react-oauth/google

```
import { Button, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { GoogleOAuthProvider, useGoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google"

const googleClientId = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID

const googleIcon = (
  <img alt="google" src="/static/images/icons/google-icon.svg" />
)

const GoogleLoginComponent = () => {
  const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    flow: 'implicit',
    onSuccess: async (tokenResponse) => {
      try {
        console.log(tokenResponse)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
    onError: (errorResponse) => console.log(errorResponse)
  })

  return (
    <Button
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      startIcon={googleIcon}
      onClick={() => googleLogin()}
      sx={{
        padding: "11px 15px",
        "& .MuiButton-startIcon": {
          position: "absolute",
          left: "15px",
        },
        textTransform: "capitalize",
        color: "black",
      }}
    >
      <Typography component="span">Continue with Google</Typography>
    </Button>
  )
}

const CustomGoogleLogin = () => {
  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={googleClientId}>
      <GoogleLoginComponent />
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  )
}

export default CustomGoogleLogin
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LB2E.png)

I can get access Token successfully but above error occurs.
Pls help me

I want to fix the error when implement google login

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is a bug.
I got the same error when I tried to use the latest version of angular.
This meta in the header would solve it:

```
<meta
   http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy"
   content="allow-popups"
/>
```

But it doesn't work on chrome and edge.

If you are making this project to learn react, use firefox.
On firefox, it works without the meta above.
But I know, this is not a real solution if you develop
a production ready system.
I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: I still got same error...

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue add the following to your index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" content="same-origin" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).