# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call error shows up in the console while opening a google popup

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I use @react-oauth/google library. When I start google login flow, the google popup opens and I see this error in the developer tools(see an attached image). I used the demo page of this library in order to show an error. Just to make sure that the demo has the same issue.
[image: The error shows up when I press "Login with google" button and google popup opens]. Please help to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76659128/cross-origin-opener-policy-policy-would-block-the-window-closed-call)